# null value in column "center_id" violates not-null constraint (Odoo)

Tags: python, null, odoo

Why do i get this error message when i want to insert a person into a project in odoo?

```
ERROR odoo.sql_db: bad query: b'INSERT INTO "project_profile_rel" ("id", "no_counter", "state", "locked", "note", "profile_id", "p_id", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval(\'project_profile_rel_id_seq\'), 0, \'new\', false, \'\', 1057312, NULL, 1, 1, (now() at time zone \'UTC\'), (now() at time zone \'UTC\')) RETURNING id'
ERROR: null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (173192916, null, 1057312, null, f, null, new, null, 1, 2022-04-10 12:03:46.078911, 1, 2022-04-10 12:03:46.078911, , null, 0, null, null, null, null).
```

Comment: Simply .. You aren't insert a value for this field 'project_id' and you must add value for it to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because the project( `p_id`) is null and it shouldn't be null because the `profile_id` and `p_id` shouldn't be null in the table `project_profile_rel`

Check the value of `p_id` in your insert:

```
INSERT INTO "project_profile_rel" ("id", "no_counter", "state", "locked", "note", "profile_id", "p_id", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date")
                            VALUES(nextval(\'project_profile_rel_id_seq\'), 0, \'new\', false, \'\', 1057312, NULL, 1, 1, (now() at time zone \'UTC\'), (now() at time zone \'UTC\')) RETURNING id'
```